# Break up variable into array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, variables

I'd like to take a variable that I have, and turn it into an array separated by the character of my choosing. In the example below, that separator is `%`

```
dump = "1%2%3%apple%car%yellow"
```

into

```
Array= [1,2,3,apple,car,yellow]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split):

```
"1%2%3%apple%car%yellow".split('%')
# => ["1", "2", "3", "apple", "car", "yellow"]
```

*(Note that every element of the returned array is a string, even the ones containing digits.)*

From the docs:

> **split (pattern=$;, [limit]) → anArray**
>
> Divides
>   str into substrings based on a delimiter, returning an array of these
>   substrings.

You can pass a string like above (`'%'`), or a regular expression.